# Dockerfile error " port is already allocated". How to solve this problem?

Tags: docker

So I'm trying to run Docker from the VS code plug in,

Trying to build a Docker image, to see if it works.

And I get this error message

> > Executing command: `docker run --rm -it  -p 3000:3000/tcp -p 5000:5000/tcp ecommerce:latest`
>
> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external
> connectivity on endpoint clever_hermann
> (4c4b6a299257d59a8bad812ee498ecbe689a1e134492dfbb8d9da4dc2acfee35):
> Bind for 0.0.0.0:5000 failed: port is already allocated. The terminal
> process "/usr/bin/zsh '-c', 'docker run --rm -it  -p 3000:3000/tcp -p
> 5000:5000/tcp ecommerce:latest'" terminated with exit code: 125.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

Any clues on how to continue?

Comment: Do you have any other app running on your port 5000? (host port, not the guest)

Comment: apparently I do, but I have no idea how to check that out. I dont even know what a port is, in the IT meaning. But issue solved with the answer below

Comment: Of course is solved. Because it's not using the port 5000. The 5000 is not reserved. Maybe you did a npm server run on 5000 or a other service

Comment: @mommonteirocl I dont understand. What thing is not using port 5000? what does "the port 5000 is not reserved"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because some other apps or containers are running on your machine and aquired those port numbers. But still you can run by using port-mapping changes.

```
docker run --rm -it  -p 8282:3000/tcp -p 8181:5000/tcp ecommerce:latest
```

In above command you are mapping container port `3000/tcp`to your machine `localhost:8282` and same for `5000/tcp`.

Once containers are running then goto browser `http://localhost:8181` and `http://localhost:8282` for respective output

Comment: @MrFacundo if this solved the problem please accept my answer !!

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: @MrFacundo there is button ✔ on the left side of my answer so click on that. Just below of upvote and downvote button

Comment: oh cool, I didn't know I was supposed to do that. Thanks Again

Just out of curiosity, how is that useful to you (or any other user)? you get points? what do you do with these points, land jobs?

Comment: @MrFacundo this will just give some points to me and you also. No no this will not land anyone on jobs. If you accept the answer it will be helpful for others in future if anyone get's same problem then they look at accepted answer first. that's it !!